# javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1391: Servlet.init() for servlet <project>.webservice.ApplicationConfig threw exception

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

What could be the cause for this error while running my Java EE 6 app from embedded container using Eclipse?

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1391: Servlet.init() for servlet <project>.webservice.ApplicationConfig threw exception

root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Edit: Basically since I ran it successfully, I upgraded eclipse and made some changes in project (refactor/renaming variables) and svn repository setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that there were some libraries missing...including Glassfish 3.1.2 being the major one from "Web"'s "Java Build Path > Libraries".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestions Google produces when you search for `PWC1391`? Namely resolving potential version conflicts with the Jersey library (i.e. removing it from project).